# index not being recognized in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a master dataframe "master_df" that has as dates in one column and a list of dataframes in another column.

In each dataframe within the master_df there is a column for dates, and a price associated with each date.

I tried doing the following:

```
prices = []
for index, row in master_df.iterrows():
    pre_data = pd.read_csv(Path + row['Dataframe'] + '.csv')
    data = pre_data.set_index('Date')
    prices.append(data.loc[row['Date'], 'Price'])
```

This produces the error:
    'the label [12/22/2002] is not in the index'

What's confusing is that when I do the same thing, but enter in the date manually, it works:

```
for index, row in master_df.iterrows():
    pre_data = pd.read_csv(Path + row['Dataframe'] + '.csv')
    data = pre_data.set_index('Date')
    prices.append(data.loc['12/22/2002', 'Price'])
```

I checked the datatype of my index after I set it to date, and it is in a string.  I'm stumped as to why it doesn't work when I grab with "row['Date']" when it's being read as a string, but it does work when entered manually.

I realize there may be an easier way to grab these prices, keep in mind this is a part of a large complex function, so I am just trying to figure out this specific error.  In other words, I have to grab it with row['Date']. Please advise as to how I can work around this error.

Thank you!

Comment: looks like pandas has your string inside a list, e.g. ```[ '12/22/2002']``` and you want ```'12/22/2002'```. Try ```row['Date'].values``` or ```row['Date'].T.values```

Comment: If possible, post a sample of _pre\_data_ and _data_

Comment: I tried row['Date'].values and row['Date'].T.values, and neither worked unfortunately.

Comment: I'm not sure how you data is stored in both dataframes without you showing it or using ```dataframe.dtypes```. You may need ```.astype(str)``` or ```pd.to_datetime()``` depending on if you have your column stored as strings in row/master_df and in data. Please show an example of what your data looks like.

Comment: pre_data has the columns 'Contract Name' (which is the name of the child data frame), 'Date', and 'Price"

Comment: 'data' is simply the pre_data, with the index set to be the date

Answer (score 0):

What is the data type in master_df in "Date" column"? Maybe it's date? If so then 
row['Date'].strftime("%m/%d/%Y") should help.

```
prices = []
for index, row in master_df.iterrows():
    pre_data = pd.read_csv(Path + row['Dataframe'] + '.csv')
    data = pre_data.set_index('Date')
    prices.append(data.loc[row['Date'].strftime("%m/%d/%Y"), 'Price'])
```

Comment: It's in a string format in the master_df, and like I said when I checked the data type on the row['Date'], it returned <str>